# Inheriting AppCompatActivity and ListActivity

Tags: java, android

As far as I am aware, Java does not support multiple inheritance.  Because of this, I'm unsure how to implement an ActionBar and a List View when each class has to be inherited.

Currently I am getting an error with the `getListView` method, as my activity currently extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Here is my Java class:

```
    public class EmergencyContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_contacts);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String [] contacts = {"XX Gas Emergency Service", "XXFire Service", "Council"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Reasonably new to Java and Android.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: `ListActivity`is already `Activity`  You not need to extend another one .

Comment: `Error:(25, 9) error: cannot find symbol method getListView()`.  The application runs without crashing, however, the list does not appear as hoped. @ShaluTD

Comment: There is no method like getListView() in AppCompatActivity class

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to inherit from `ListActivity` to use a `ListView`. `ListView` is a widget. You are welcome to use `ListView` in an `AppCompatActivity`, the same way that you would use `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button`, `ImageView`, `RecyclerView`, etc.:

- Put a `ListView` in a layout resource (e.g., `res/layout/activity_emergency_contacts.xml`), perhaps alongside other widgets
- Call `setContentView()` to have your activity use that layout resource
- Call `findViewById()` to retrieve the `ListView`